# The file format and extension of filename.csv don't match

Tags: vba

I saved a file in .csv format using VBA. Below is the code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "FilePath" & Format(Now() - 3, "mm.dd.yy") & ".csv"
```

The file is saved successfully. However, while opening the file, it is throwing the error "The file format and extension of filename.csv don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe". I am trying to suppress this warning message. It would be great if someone helps me to know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess you are missing the fileformat.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="FilePath" & Format(Now() - 3, "mm.dd.yy") & ".csv", _
  FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

If this Fileformat is not working, you can have a look in the following link,
where you can find more versions for using CSV:)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great! Actually, I tried FileFormat before I posted the code here. I missed the column I think. Thanks again for helping!!